# Why do running a python script (executable) on Multi2sim gives an error "Invalid ELF file"?

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I am trying to run a simple Hello world python script on Multi2sim (simulator for CPUs and GPUs to test & validate new hardware designs).

I am new to Multi2sim and as per my research it seems that we have to first compile any python program normally and run the executable on multi2sim.

So, I made my hello world program executable by following the steps:

1. Adding `#! /usr/bin/python` to the first line of my script.
2. Renaming the script from `hello.py` to hello.
3. Running the command `chmod +x hello.py` on the terminal.
4. Finally run the executable using `./hello`

It is perfectly executing and output the result. But I am not able to run the same executable on multi2sim using the command: `m2s ./hello`
It gives me the error: Invalid ELF file

My machine specifications are:

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS,
python 2.7 and python 3.5,
Muti2sim 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Actually, making script program exeutable is not enough to "compile" it and make it "binary".
It still stays script (the code, which needs to go through interpreter). So, generally, you want to run `m2s /usr/bin/python ./hello.py` (most of the time `python` is either binary (compiled for your architecture) or symlink to it).